# Showing Deprecation Warnings Only for a Specific Version When Testing Django

Tags: python, django, testing

I am about to upgrade from Django 1.9 to 1.10 and would like to test if I have some deprecated functionality.

However using

```
python -Wall manage.py test
```

will show tons and tons of warnings for Django 2.0. Is there a way to suppress warnings only for 2.0 or show only warnings for 1.10?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this to your `manage.py`:

```
import warnings
from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango110Warning

warnings.filterwarnings('always', category=RemovedInDjango110Warning)
```

Change `'always'` to `'default'` to ignore redundant messages or to `'error'` to cause the program to fail on warnings.

Comment: I am not sure if this is working correctly (for the record I used `python manage.py test`). There is only one warning for a middleware that needs to be included but I know for a fact that I have deprecated url patterns.

Comment: Try running `manage.py` or `manage.py runserver`. Make sure your `urls.py` are evaluated (for example by calling `reverse` or `client.get`). If you add an `assert False` to your `urls.py` and your tests still pass, then `urls.py` is not evaluated :-)

Comment: In the end the problem was that debuging was turned off with `DEBUG = False` in `settings.py`...

Answer (score 9):

A good way to limit the output to only show deprecation warnings is running:

```
python -Wd manage.py check
```

or

```
python -Wd manage.py test
```